# Set JAVA OPTS in Ant task

Tags: java, ant

How do I set the below java options in an ant task, I haven't been able to find any relevant attribute.

What I want to do via an ant script is as below

`java -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true  com.something.class`

I have the below ant snippet but not sure how to add the `-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true`

```
<target name="start.ab.cd" >
        <java  classname="com.something.class" failonerror="yes">
                    <arg line="${d} ${e} ${f} />
                    <classpath>
                            <pathelement location="${client.classes.dir}/something.jar"/>
                            <pathelement path="${ex.classpath}"/>
                    </classpath>
        </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the doc for the ['java' task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html), you can use `<jvmarg>` nested elements for JVM options, e.g.:

```
<jvmarg value="-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true"/>
```

To set system properties, you can use the `<sysproperty>` nested element instead:

```
<sysproperty key="sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arg value to do this:

```
 <arg value="-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true"/>
```